# pandas get data for the end day of month?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

The data is given as following:

```
             return 
2010-01-04  0.016676    
2010-01-05  0.003839
...
2010-01-05  0.003839
2010-01-29  0.001248
2010-02-01  0.000134
...
```

What I want get is to extract all value that is the last day of month **appeared in the data** .

```
2010-01-29  0.00134
2010-02-28  ......
```

If I directly use pandas.resample, i.e., df.resample('M).last(). I would select the correct rows with the wrong index. (it automatically use the last day of the month as the index)

```
2010-01-31  0.00134
2010-02-28  ......
```

How can I get the correct answer in a Pythonic way?

Comment: thanks for the `.last()` at the end of the resample, didn't know it was available and it did what I needed since I didn't need the exact index date.

Answer (score 15):

An assumption made here is that your date data is part of the index. If not, I recommend setting it first.

#### Single Year

I don't think the resampling or grouper functions would do. Let's group on the month number instead and call `DataFrameGroupBy.tail`.

```
df.groupby(df.index.month).tail(1)
```

---

#### Multiple Years

If your data spans multiple years, you'll need to group on the year and month. Using a single grouper created from `dt.strftime`—

```
df.groupby(df.index.strftime('%Y-%m')).tail(1)
```

Or, using multiple groupers—

```
df.groupby([df.index.year, df.index.month]).tail(1)
```

Note—if your index is *not* a `DatetimeIndex` as assumed here, you'll need to replace `df.index` with `pd.to_datetime(df.index, errors='coerce')` above.

Answer (score 6):

Although this doesn't answer the question properly I'll leave it if someone is interested.

**An approach** which would only work **if you are certain you have all days** (**!IMPORTANT)** is to  add 1 day too with pd.Timedelta and check if day == 1. I did a small running time test and it is **6x** faster than the groupby solution.

```
df[(df['dates'] + pd.Timedelta(days=1)).dt.day == 1]
```

Or if index:

```
df[(df.index + pd.Timedelta(days=1)).day == 1]
```

---

**Full example:**

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({
    'dates': pd.date_range(start='2016-01-01', end='2017-12-31'),
    'i': 1
}).set_index('dates')

dfout = df[(df.index + pd.Timedelta(days=1)).day == 1]
print(dfout)
```

Returns:

```
           i
dates        
2016-01-31  1
2016-02-29  1
2016-03-31  1
2016-04-30  1
2016-05-31  1
2016-06-30  1
2016-07-31  1
2016-08-31  1
2016-09-30  1
2016-10-31  1
2016-11-30  1
2016-12-31  1
2017-01-31  1
2017-02-28  1
2017-03-31  1
2017-04-30  1
2017-05-31  1
2017-06-30  1
2017-07-31  1
2017-08-31  1
2017-09-30  1
2017-10-31  1
2017-11-30  1
2017-12-31  1
```